# XSSFWorkbook Creation failure

Tags: apache, apache-poi

> I am creating .xlsx file using poi jars which are poi-3.15.jar, poi-ooxml->3.15.jar, poi-ooxml-schemas-3.15.jar, ooxml-schemas-1.3.jar, xml-apis->2.0.2.jar, xbean-2.2.0, xmlschema-1.4.7.jar and commons-collections4-.4.0.jar.>
>  **But still im getting follwoing error.**
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.commons.collections4.ListValuedMap
>   
> can you please help me to create simple .xlsx file using >XSSFWorkbook class.

Comment: ListValuedMap exception was resolved after changed from commons-collections4-4.0 to commons-collections4-4.1.jar. But now im getting "XML-BEANS compiled schema: Incompatible minor version - expecting up to 23, got 24 (schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sF1327CCA741569E70F9CA8C9AF9B44B2.index) - code 3" error. can you please help on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListValuedMap` is contained in this jar: [commons-collections4](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-collections4/4.0). You should also use Xml Beans 2.3.0 or later.

Comment: XML-BEANS compiled schema: Incompatible minor version - expecting up to 23,XML-BEANS compiled schema: Incompatible minor version - expecting up to 23, got 24 (schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sF1327CCA741569E70F9CA8C9AF9B44B2.index) - code  ....... getting this error.

Comment: @KVijayBhaskar try adding XMLBeans 2.3 or later.

Comment: Thanks you so much @peterremec.  After added xmlbeans 2.3.0 version, the xlsx sheet created successfully.

Comment: @KVijayBhaskar no problem. I updated my answer with full solution, so you can except it.

Comment: I have applied same jars in my real time project while creating XSSFWorkbook, im getting same error which is "org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaTypeLoaderException: XML-BEANS compiled schema: Incompatible minor version - expecting up to 23, got 24 (schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sF1327CCA741569E70F9CA8C9AF9B44B2.index) - code 3". Earlier using those jars, i created local. so that it was worked as expected. But now im facing issue in current project..... please advice on this...

Comment: Are there multiple XmlBeans jars? Use only one, e.g. version 2.3.0.